# Creating animated text effects using NSLayoutManager?

Tags: ios, animation, uilabel, textkit, nslayoutmanager

In session 220 (Advanced Text Layouts and Effects with Text Kit) of [WWDC 2013](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/) they specifically say [`NSLayoutManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/NSLayoutManager_Class_TextKit/) can be used in conjunction with `NSTextStorage` and `NSTextContainer` to create advanced text animations. They don't say how.

I want to use `NSLayoutManager`/`NSTextStorage`/`NSTextContainer` to create custom text animation. To put it simply, I want to animate size and position of individual glyphs and fade and unfade specific glyphs.

There seems to be no dedicated methods nor documentation for animations with `NSLayoutManager` and the only tutorial on the matter I found [is here](http://swiftyeti.com/texteffects-with-nslayoutmanager/). However, it shows how to hack `NSLayoutManager` into animations rather than how to *use it the way it is supposed to be used* (they create `CATextLayer` for each individual glyph!).

Can somebody point me to the right direction? I know how to use `NSLayoutManager` / `NSTextStorage` / `NSTextContainer` to render static text. Some demo, showing the principles of animating text with `NSLayoutManager` would be be perfect. Just to get me started I can figure out details myself.

Comment: Have you found any more information on this?

Comment: @DannyZlobinsky Not really. There was an answer here from high reputation user but aparently was deleted (?!). I am still waiting for some good answers.

Comment: Here a good video tutorial where shows NSTextStorage principles. I hope it could help you something that is there but it looks interesting:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7trOFDGVwA

Answer (score 2):

`NSTextContainer、NSLayoutManager、NSTextStorage` is new to iOS7:

1) NSTextContainer:

> The NSTextContainer class defines a region in which text is laid out.
>   An NSTextContainer object defines rectangular regions, and you can define exclusion paths inside the textcontainer'sboundingrectanglesothattextflowsaroundtheexclusionpathasitislaidout.

2) NSLayoutManager:

> An NSLayoutManager object coordinates the layout and display of characters held in an NSTextStorage object. It maps Unicode character codes to glyphs, sets the glyphs in a series of NSTextContainer objects, and displays them in a series of text view objects.

3) NSTextStorage:

> NSTextStorage is a semiconcrete subclass of NSMutableAttributedString that manages a set of client NSLayoutManagerobjects,notifyingthemofanychangestoitscharactersorattributessothattheycanrelay and redisplay the text as needed.

We could know `NSTextStorage` can store and manage `UITextView`'s text,and it is `NSMutableAttributedString`'s subclass.We can add or modify the attributes, so it is a good choice to store and manage `UITextView`'s text.

`NSLayoutManager` use for manage the content of `NSTextStorage`'s layout.

`NSTextContainer` provide a rectangle to stash the layouted text.

We can simply use them:

```
CGRect textViewRect = CGRectInset(self.view.bounds, 10.0, 20.0);

// NSTextContainer
NSTextContainer *container = [[NSTextContainer alloc] initWithSize:CGSizeMake(textViewRect.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)]; // new in iOS 7.0
container.widthTracksTextView = YES; // Controls whether the receiveradjusts the width of its bounding rectangle when its text view is resized


// NSLayoutManager
NSLayoutManager *layoutManager = [[NSLayoutManager alloc] init]; // new in iOS 7.0
[layoutManager addTextContainer:container];


// NSTextStorage subclass
self.textStorage = [[TextStorage alloc] init]; // new in iOS 7.0
[self.textStorage addLayoutManager:layoutManager];
```

Firstly is make instance of them, and create thier relationship.You must add `NSTextContainer` in `UITextView` by `initWithFrame:textContainer:` method.

```
// UITextView
UITextView *newTextView = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:textViewRect textContainer:container];
newTextView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
newTextView.scrollEnabled = YES;
newTextView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;
// newTextView.editable = NO;
newTextView.font = [UIFont fontWithName:self.textStorage.fontName size:18.0];
newTextView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
self.textView = newTextView;
[self.view addSubview:self.textView];
```

If want to use `UITextStorage` to change text's attributes, you can use:

```
[_textStorage beginEditing];  // begin edit
[_textStorage endEditing];  // end edit
```

Between them you can edit text, such as:

```
[_textStorage beginEditing];
NSDictionary *attrsDic = @{NSTextEffectAttributeName: NSTextEffectLetterpressStyle};
UIKIT_EXTERN NSString *const NSTextEffectAttributeName NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(7_0);          // NSString, default nil: no text effect
NSMutableAttributedString *mutableAttrString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Letterpress" attributes:attrsDic];
NSAttributedString *appendAttrString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" Append:Letterpress"];
[mutableAttrString appendAttributedString:appendAttrString];
[_textStorage setAttributedString:mutableAttrString];
[_textStorage endEditing];
```

Or change color:

```
[_textStorage beginEditing];
/* Dynamic Coloring Text */
self.textStorage.bookItem = [[BookItem alloc] initWithBookName:@"Dynamic Coloring.rtf"];
self.textStorage.tokens = @{@"Alice": @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor redColor]},
                            @"Rabbit": @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor greenColor]},
                            DefaultTokenName: @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName: [UIColor blackColor]}
                            };
[_textStorage setAttributedString:_textStorage.bookItem.content];
[_textStorage endEditing];
```